# Pressure in waves on a string

Tags: waves, string

We know that when we speak sound waves are created. The air particles compress and rarefy and pressure is more at the nodes and less at anti-nodes.  But can we say the same thing about waves on a string,- that pressure is more at the nodes than the anti-nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Waves on a string are [transverse waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_wave) not [longitudinal waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_wave). They are not variations in pressure, but variations in the displacement of the string. The (average) displacement is greatest at the anti-nodes and zero at the nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly explaining John's answer - but *visually*..!

When you wiggle a sting (using a good resonator), you'd see something like this... The structure clearly reveals **Transverse** vibrations.

[image: String]

If you still don't understand, [Here's a good simulation](http://phet.colorado.edu/sims/wave-on-a-string/wave-on-a-string_en.html) for that...